# Replacing logical operators with cell references excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have trouble understanding how I can use logical operators placed in cells outside of a COUNTIF. If I try with an IF and AVERAGEIF where there is no separator in between the range and criteria, like COUNTIF(RANGE,CRITERIA) then excel just outputs the logical operator referenced as a string.

Is there any easy way to do this? I also tried the INDIRECT function instead of just &cellref&

[image]

..this outputs "1" when 3% as it is lower than or equal to 5%

[image]

..this outputs "0.03<=0.03"

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
I changed it to: AND(COUNTIF(H5,E4&AVERAGE(F5:G5)). And since I compare more than just H5 then I can just add to it like this:

AND(COUNTIF(H5,E4&AVERAGE(F5:G5),COUNTIF(I5,E4&AVERAGE(F5:G5))
..to check if both H5 and I5 is less than the average of F5 and G5